# Open inside and outside of WebView

Tags: java, webview

I want open my website and Facebook (Facebook logging plugin) in a `WebView` only. All other external links will open in other external browsers. Below code allows Facebook to open in external browsers.

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
{
    if (!url.contains ("https://kroybook.com/')'https://facebook.com/")
    {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri), "Choose browser"));

        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
    } else {
        myWebView.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What `WebView` class are you using? What Java GUI framework?

Answer (score 0):

This the code that worked:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url != null && url.startsWith("whatsapp://")) {
        view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```